# Serialize Kendo UI MVC MultiSelect as array

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have this Kendo UI multiselect:

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
      .Name("EditModel.Modules.ID")
      .DataValueField("ID")
      .DataTextField("Name")
      .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
      .DataSource(source =>
      {
        source.Read(read =>
                    {
                    read.Action("GetModules", "Modules");
                    })
                   .ServerFiltering(true);
                    }))
```

How can I add [*index*] to name so the array maps to the array in my editmodel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(model => model.Property))
```

It is important that you must not the Name() in this case (it will be set automatically to the correct value).